# Как в localstorage массиве удалить конкретное значение

Tags: javascript

У меня в localstorage по ключу cartItems есть значения в виде массива ["1", "2"] как я могу удалить конкретно к примеру второе значение то есть "2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Получить строковое значение из `localStorage` по ключу.
2. Перевести его из строки в массив, если оно не `null` - `JSON.parse`.
3. Удалить из массива все, что нужно - методами `shift`/`pop`/`splice` (или, формированием нового массива из данных старого).
4. Сохранить строковое представление (`JSON.stringify`) в `localStorage`.